# Android- Dropbox api always requesting to link account

Tags: android, api, mobile, dropbox

I'm integrating the Dropbox core api so my app can store files and retrieve files. The problem is every time I access dropbox, it requests I link the account again. I post the code I'm using to login and store my dropbox tokens.

```
public static DropBoxManager getInstance(Context context){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new DropBoxManager();
            this.context = context;

            prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(DB_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            AndroidAuthSession session = loadDBSession();
            mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);


        }
        return instance;
    }

private static AndroidAuthSession loadDBSession(){
    AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
    return loadAuthToken(session);
}

/**
 * This method starts the auth process for Dropbox. 
 * The API will launch a webview if needed for the auth to our app.
 * Listen in oResume to call auth successful.  
 * if needed. 
 * @param activty
 */
public static void startOAuth2(Activity activity){
    if (!mDBApi.getSession().isLinked()) {
        mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(activity);
    }else{
        executeDropboxProcess();
    }
}

public static boolean isAuthenticationSuccessful(){
    if (mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
        try {
            // Required to complete auth, sets the access token on the session
            mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();
            storeAuthToken(mDBApi.getSession());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e("DbAuthLog", "Error authenticating", e);
            return false; 
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean storeAuthToken(AndroidAuthSession session){
        String oauth2AccessToken = session.getOAuth2AccessToken();
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, "oauth2:");
        edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, oauth2AccessToken);
        boolean success = edit.commit();
        return success;
    }
private static AndroidAuthSession loadAuthToken(AndroidAuthSession session) {
    String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
    String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
    Log.i(TAG, "pulling stored data ");
    Log.i(TAG, "ACCESS_KEY_NAME " + key);
    Log.i(TAG, "secret(oauth2AccessToken) " + secret);

    if (key == null || secret == null || key.length() == 0 || secret.length() == 0){
        return session;
    }
    if (key.equals("oauth2:")) {//aiming for OAuth2 only
        session.setOAuth2AccessToken(secret);
        AccessTokenPair accessTokenPair = new AccessTokenPair(key, secret);
        session.setAccessTokenPair(accessTokenPair);
    }
    return session;
}

private static void clearAuth() {
    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.clear();
    edit.commit();
}
```

Comment: The auth flow is initiated by `startOAuth2Authentication`, which in your code is gated by `mDBApi.getSession().isLinked()`, in your `startOAuth2` method. When are you calling `startOAuth2`?  Are you sure `loadAuthToken` was called successfully before doing so? If the OAuth 2 access token wasn't set successfully, `isLinked` will return false. You may want to add some more logging in `loadAuthToken` to make sure it's working as expected.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I will post more of the code this evening. But I do have the startOAuth2Authentication method and everything seems to be flew properly until I believe the loadAuthToken